# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)in creating a Sphereface model using lfw dataset and mtcnn model

Tags: python, face-recognition, valueerror

I am trying to create a Sphereface model using lfw dataset and mtcnn model to show evaluation values like precision, recall, F1 score etc. without using dlib library.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, average_precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from joblib import dump
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from tqdm import tqdm

# Load the LFW dataset
def load_lfw_dataset(data_folder):
    images = []
    labels = []

    for person_name in os.listdir(data_folder):
        person_folder = os.path.join(data_folder, person_name)
        if os.path.isdir(person_folder):
            for filename in os.listdir(person_folder):
                if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                    image_path = os.path.join(person_folder, filename)
                    images.append(cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
                    labels.append(person_name)

    return images, labels

# Detect and align faces using MTCNN
def detect_and_align_faces(images):
    detector = MTCNN()
    aligned_faces = []

    for img in images:
        faces = detector.detect_faces(img)

        if faces:
            x, y, w, h = faces[0]['box']
            face = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            aligned_faces.append(face)

    return aligned_faces

# Sphereface-like model architecture (example, adjust as needed)
class SphereFaceModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(SphereFaceModel, self).__init__()
        # Example: Add Sphereface model layers

    def forward(self, x):
        # Example: Forward pass
        return x

# Extract features using Sphereface
def extract_features(model, aligned_faces):
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.Resize((112, 96)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5]),
    ])

    features = []

    for face in aligned_faces:
        face = transform(face)
        face = face.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

        # Example: Forward pass through the Sphereface model
        output = model(face)
        features.append(output.detach().numpy())

    return np.array(features)

# Train the Sphereface model (example, adjust as needed)
def train_sphereface_model(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, num_epochs=5):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_loader):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

# Main function
def main():
    # Load LFW dataset
    data_folder = "lfw"  # Change this to the actual path of your LFW dataset
    images, labels = load_lfw_dataset(data_folder)

    # Split the dataset into training and testing sets
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    # Detect and align faces
    X_train_aligned = detect_and_align_faces(X_train)
    X_test_aligned = detect_and_align_faces(X_test)

    # Example: Initialize Sphereface model (adjust as needed)
    num_classes = len(set(y_train))
    model = SphereFaceModel(num_classes)

    # Extract features
    X_train_features = extract_features(model, X_train_aligned)
    X_test_features = extract_features(model, X_test_aligned)

    # Train SVM classifier on extracted features
    classifier = make_pipeline(OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(probability=True)))
    classifier.fit(X_train_features.reshape(X_train_features.shape[0], -1), y_train)

    # Save the trained model
    model_filename = 'sphereface_model.joblib'
    dump(classifier, model_filename)  # Adjust the filename as needed

    # Evaluate the model
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test_features.reshape(X_test_features.shape[0], -1))

    # Confusion matrix
    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()

    # Precision, Recall, F1 Score
    precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
    recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
    f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')

    # ROC Curve and AUC
    y_test_bin = label_binarize(y_test, classes=np.unique(y_test))
    y_pred_prob = classifier.predict_proba(X_test_features.reshape(X_test_features.shape[0], -1))

    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test_bin.ravel(), y_pred_prob.ravel())
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

    # Mean Average Precision
    average_precision = average_precision_score(y_test_bin, y_pred_prob, average='micro')

    # Equal Error Rate (EER)
    eer = 0.5 * (1 - recall_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=0))

    # Print the results
    print(f'True Positive: {tp}')
    print(f'True Negative: {tn}')
    print(f'False Positive: {fp}')
    print(f'False Negative: {fn}')
    print(f'Precision: {precision}')
    print(f'Recall: {recall}')
    print(f'F1 Score: {f1}')
    print(f'ROC AUC: {roc_auc}')
    print(f'Mean Average Precision: {average_precision}')
    print(f'Equal Error Rate: {eer}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\E N\Desktop\Face Recognition Models\Sphereface\lfw_main.py", line 156, in 
main()
File "c:\Users\E N\Desktop\Face Recognition Models\Sphereface\lfw_main.py", line 100, in main
X_train_aligned = detect_and_align_faces(X_train)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\E N\Desktop\Face Recognition Models\Sphereface\lfw_main.py", line 40, in detect_and_align_faces
faces = detector.detect_faces(img)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\E N\Desktop\Face Recognition Models\Sphereface.venv\Lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py", line 287, in detect_faces
height, width, _ = img.shape
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
How do I make it work and apply it to other face recognition algorithms?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: which line makes problem? You didn't show FULL error message so we can't see it. And don't expect that we will run code to see full error message. Besides code may work correctly on our computers. We can't see your screen and we can't read in your mind - you have to show ALL details in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for your error I can see is that  your function `detect_and_align_faces()` expects a list of cv2 images but gets something else ([Check](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) what `train_test_split()` returns).

Then check what `img` at

```
for img in images:
        faces = detector.detect_faces(img)
```

is in fact.